# Mysql query taking long time when using variable

Tags: mysql

```
SET @acounts = 0;
SET @bcounts = 0;
SET @cur_year = '2015';
SET @userId = "m00087654";

SELECT *, (@acounts :=@acounts+1) as id FROM (
SELECT distinct  userId,cid  FROM `TABLE`
WHERE user_id = @userId AND ntype = 'parta'   AND date_from <>  date_to AND  YEAR(ndate) = @cur_year 
ORDER BY ndate, cid) AS a;
```

Time taken 1.22 sec

```
 SELECT *, (@acounts :=@acounts+1) as id FROM (
SELECT distinct  userId,cid  FROM `TABLE`
WHERE user_id = "m00087654" AND ntype = 'parta'   AND date_from <>  date_to AND  YEAR(ndate) = @cur_year 
ORDER BY ndate, cid) AS a;
```

Time taken 0.0022 sec

when i put user_id = @userId then it take more time comparing  user_id = "m00087654"

Any clue why taking more time ?

Comment: What happens when you use `SET @cur_year = 2015;` (int instead of string)?

Comment: no differance for year. Only prob when using user_id = @userId

Comment: only prob in user_id = @userId